# Background music with appending an Object to the DOM by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mp3, jsfiddle

I would like to make a simple webpage, with online streaming radio background music or talk shows playing in the background. I followed the method described here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/hgxRgmT0INY/KR-CGxqdlN4J

It works in Chrome:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language=javascript>

function setupSound() 
{ 
  var obj = document.createElement("object"); 
  obj.width="0px"; 
  obj.height="0px"; 
  obj.type = "audio/mp3"; 
  obj.data = "http://mr-stream.mediaconnect.hu/4736/mr1.mp3";
  obj.setAttribute("id", "bgsound1");
  var paramobj=obj.appendChild(document.createElement('param'));
  paramobj.name="loop";
  paramobj.value="-1";
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
  body.appendChild(obj); 
  document.getElementsByName("button1")[0].onclick=function(){change_channel()};                        
} 

function change_channel()
{
var channels=[
 ["Music: MR1-Kossuth","http://mr-stream.mediaconnect.hu/4736/mr1.mp3"],
 ["Music: none",""],
 ["Music: MKR","http://katolikusradio.hu:9000/live_hi.mp3"],
 ["Music: Karc FM","http://hosting.42netmedia.com:13100/;stream#.mp3"],
]   

var channel_hash={};
var nextindex=0;
for (var i=0;i<=channels.length-1;i++) {
  nextindex=(i+1) % channels.length;
  channel_hash[channels[i][0]]=[channels[nextindex][0],channels[nextindex][1]]; 
 }

 document.getElementById("bgsound1").data=channel_hash[f2.button1.value][1]
 f2.button1.value=channel_hash[f2.button1.value][0]

}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="setupSound()">

 <center>
     <form name='f2'>
       <input type=button name='button1' value='Music: MR1-Kossuth'>
     </form>
 </center>

</body>
</html>
```

I made this JSFiddle, but it doesn't play the channels, no sound at all:
https://jsfiddle.net/gxeqsnL3/1/
I think the sound object is not attached to the DOM properly, because of the iframes.
However the code works in Google Chrome, the background music plays nicely from the streaming radio channels.

My main problem is: when I want to switch to the channel of which URL contains a semicolon, I get a download document from the browser. However the semicolon is really needed, because without it the ShoutCast radio stream doesn't play properly even in a HTML5 audio player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed a bit your code.
It's the same behaviour but instead of creating a `<object>` HTML element, I create a `new Audio` object in JavaScript, without messing with HTML tags.

```js
var audio = new Audio();
document.getElementsByName("button1")[0].onclick = change_channel;

function change_channel() {
  var nextindex = 0;
  var channels = [
    ["Music: MKR", "http://katolikusradio.hu:9000/live_hi.mp3"],
    ["Music: MR1-Kossuth", "http://mr-stream.mediaconnect.hu/4736/mr1.mp3"],
    ["Music: none", ""],
    ["Music: Karc FM", "http://hosting.42netmedia.com:13100/\;stream#.mp3"]
  ];
  var channel_hash = {};

  for (var i = 0; i <= channels.length - 1; i++) {
    nextindex = (i + 1) % channels.length;
    channel_hash[channels[i][0]] = [channels[nextindex][0], channels[nextindex][1]];
  }

  playSound(channel_hash[f2.button1.value][1]);
  f2.button1.value = channel_hash[f2.button1.value][0];
}

function playSound(file) {
  if (file === "") {
    console.log("Now playing: none");
    audio.pause();
  } else {
    console.log("Now playing: " + file);
    audio.pause();
    audio = new Audio(file);
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <form name='f2'>
    <input type=button name='button1' value='Music: none'>
  </form>
</center>
```

**jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/stag9p3r

Comment: Interesting, no sound for me at all. I can change channels, by clicking the button, but sound doesn't play. I tried 3 browsers. I am using Arch Linux, XFCE. This version contains the URL with semicolon: http://jsfiddle.net/gxeqsnL3/19/

Comment: I build the same behaviour but instead of creating a `<object>` HTML element, just using Audio object in JavaScript. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/stag9p3r/ and let me know if it works for you. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i made some new code for you that might help you understand!

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="music_button" onclick="change_music()" value="No music">
<audio controls style="display:none" id="music" src="">
</audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var channels = [
    ["Music: MKR", "http://katolikusradio.hu:9000/live_hi.mp3"],
    ["Music: MR1-Kossuth", "http://mr-stream.mediaconnect.hu/4736/mr1.mp3"],
    ["Music: Karc FM", "http://hosting.42netmedia.com:13100/\;stream#.mp3"]
  ];
var current_channel = 0;

function change_music() {
var button = document.getElementById("music_button")
var music = document.getElementById("music")
if(current_channel > 2) {
current_channel = 0;
button.value="No Music"
music.src = "";
music.load()
music.play()
}
else {
button.value = channels[current_channel][0]
music.src = channels[current_channel][1]
music.load()
music.play()
current_channel++
}

}
```